# FROM syntax is not executed on Fuseki-server

Tags: java, sparql, jena, fuseki

I have run the following statement on the Fuseki-server.

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object  
FROM <https://jdh0139q.databox.me/profile/card#me>  
WHERE { ?subject ?predicate ?object } LIMIT 25
```

However, the results were not output.

When ARQ was executed on the command line, the result was output.

I would be grateful if you could tell me what the problem is.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? read from the web, or extract a graph from the local dataset and query that? For the first, use the general SPARQL processor (only in fuseki-basic, not the one with the UI); for the second, that is the behaviour for recent versions when asking a dataset or its services (e.g. "/dataset/sparql")